# O que quer dizer o arroba (@) no nome de uma dependência no arquivo package.json?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Qual é o significado do símbolo @ antes de uma dependência do arquivo package.json?

Por exemplo:

```
{
  "name": "star-admin-pro-react",
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "homepage": "https://bootstrapdash.com/demo/star-admin-free/react/template/demo_1/preview",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^4.3.1", //<-----
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^4.3.0", //<-----
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^4.3.0",
    "@mdi/font": "^4.2.95",
    "@tinymce/tinymce-react": "^3.3.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Significa que o pacote está dentro de uma [organização do npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/organizations). Na maioria das vezes a organização é pública (bem como os respectivos pacotes).

Vejamos, por exemplo, o pacote `@fullcalendar/interaction`. Na verdade, o nome do pacote é somente `interaction`, mas pertence à organização `fullcalendar`.

Nesse sentido, utiliza-se a barra para "separar" o nome da organização (sempre precedido por `@`) do nome do pacote.

É, basicamente, uma diferença de apresentação. Fora isso não há diferença e comporta-se do mesmo jeito que qualquer *npm package*.